# How to fix "You cannot create a service (“request”) of an inactive scope (“request”)" error when using php-unit for testing

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

When I run my `php-unit` test, I get the following error:

`You cannot create a service (“request”) of an inactive scope (“request”)`.

It's stopping me from testing my code properly, and I'd like to be able to test my code. I'm on Symfony 2.8 with PHP 5.6.

I have found some answers to on StackO which suggest adding these lines in:

```
protected function initializeContainer() {
    parent::initializeContainer();
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli' &&  $this->getEnvironment() != 'test') {
        $this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
        $this->getContainer()->set('request', new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(), 'request');
    }
}
```

I have that added in to `AppKernel.php` but I'm still receiving that error on my test. Here's the `setUp()` and first test.

```
class HelperTest extends WebTestCase
{

  private $helper;

  public function setUp() {
    $this->client = static::createClient(array(), array(
      'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'email@address.com',
      'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'not_the_real_password_obvi',
    ));

    $container = $this->client->getContainer();
    $this->helper = $container->get('Helper');
  }

  /*
    Tests for daysToBirthdayFromNow() function;
  */

public function testDaysUntilBirthdayIs270() {

    $birthdayTimestamp = 1514764800; // 1 January 2018
    $currentTimestamp = 1538132400; // 28 September 2018

    $daysToBirthday = intval($this->helper->daysToBirthdayFromNow($birthdayTimestamp, $currentTimestamp));

    $this->assertTrue($daysToBirthday == 270);
  }
```

This calls `daysToBirthdayFromNow()`, inside of which I call another Helper function called `convertTimestampToTimezone()`. The test falls over in that function at this line of code:

`$timezoneSetting = $this->getClub()->s('timezone');`

I have dumped out `$this->getClub()` and it crashes out with the error message that is in the title of this post. Any tests that don't require `$this->` work fine.

Has anyone overcome this problem? As far as I know, it's a problem that my the dev team I work in has been unable to solve since they started using Symfony.

Comment: Request scopes turned out to not be such a good idea.  You should be using the [RequestStack](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this after consulting several other sources. Here is the fix for anyone interested:

Add this function into the `AppKernel` class:

```
protected function initializeContainer() {
    parent::initializeContainer();
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli' &&  $this->getEnvironment() != 'test') {
        $this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
        $this->getContainer()->set('request', new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request(), 'request');
    }
}
```

And at the top of my test file:

```
class HelperTest extends WebTestCase
{

  private $helper;

  public function setUp() {
    $this->client = static::createClient(array(), array(
      'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'your@email.com',
      'PHP_AUTH_PW'   => 'your_password',
    ));

    $container = $this->client->getContainer();
    $container->enterScope('request');
    $container->set('request', new Request(), 'request');

    $this->helper = $container->get('Helper');
  }

  public function tearDown() {
    $container = $this->client->getContainer();
    $container->leaveScope('request');
  }
  // Your tests go below here
```

YMMV but this works for me (finally!)

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Just be aware that if you ever plan on moving your app to Symfony 3 or beyond then the request service will no longer be available.  You will need to find where request is being used and replaced with request_stack and possible adjust a bit of logic.

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, I'm not sure what our plans are but now that 2.8 is unmaintained we probably will move. Testing will actually help us check what needs to be fixed during upgrades anyway!